# Delete from list in for-loop . Python

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for k in my_list:

    if k > 6:
        #delete k
```

How do I delete `k` from the list if it is greater than a certain value ?

Comment: You can also avoid using `for` loop by using `slice` or `set`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't change the list you are iterating over, just create a new one and assign it
to a variable:

```
my_list = [k for k in my_list if k <= 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove an element from a `list` you can use the `remove` method.
But you must take into account that removing elements while iterating over the `list` ends up in undefined behaviour. For example:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for x in L:
...     L.remove(x)
... 
>>> L   #should be empty
[2, 4]
```

If you want to avoid this you can either create a new `list` using a list-comprehension, or simply iterate over a copy of the list:

```
>>> L = range(10)
>>> [x for x in L if x <= 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for x in L[:]:
...     if x > 6:
...             L.remove(x)
... 
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
k = [i for i in k if i <= 6]
```

Or `filter` (note in Python 3 it will return a `filter` object, which you can convert into a list)

```
k = filter(lambda x: x <= 6, k)
```

The above two options will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> my_list= [i for i in my_list if i <= 6]
>>> print my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll begin loop by the end and it won't move indexes :

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for k in my_list[::-1]:

    if k > 6:
        del k
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all the elements in the list which are greater than the specified value. You can use sorting and slicing.

I suggest using set without sorting or remove or blah blah... :P

```
a = [3,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,0,7]
```

then sort

```
a = a.sort() #a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
idx = a.index(6) #idx=6
```

then slice

```
a = a[0:idx] # a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or the alternative is using the `set`. create another list using `range` of your specified limits for example you want to remove all elements from `4 to 8` then

```
rm = xrange(4,8+1)

a = list(set(a) - set(rm)) # a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 9]
```